# Symfony isGranted: Fail if attribute does not exist

Tags: error-handling, authorization, acl, symfony

I am making an authorization in application using [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) in Symfony3.

**Is there a way to cause an error, if isGranted() is called on rule* that does not exist?** Non-existent meaning, there is no logic to decide whether to allow or deny.

Because strings are used as identifiers, it is rather common IMO to make a typo or get the key wrong. In that case, the action is denied, which is ok, but I would prefer to cause 500 so that I know I ask for non-existent rule.

Is there an option to enable that? Is there a reason for this not to be a default behavior?

*Using Voters by 'rule' i mean the `attribute` and the `subject`.

Comment: You can just have your voter throw an invalid argument exception.

Comment: That does not solve anything. The voter would have to know all the rules. The point is error should be caused after all voters abstain, hence they dont [support](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/VoterInterface.html#method_supportsAttribute) the rule.

Comment: I have not done this but I suppose you could implement your own AccessDecisionManager: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#access-decision-manager Couple of other similar sof questions have more details.